# Complete ADFS login programmatically

Tags: asp.net, authentication, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, sap-enterprise-portal

I need to perform a complete AFDS login action in code. I cannot redirect the user to the ADFS login page. The user has already authenticated using a custom authentication mechanism and I use the same credentials to authenticate to ADFS, this to enable SSO to a SAP EP.

I can successfully retrieve a SAML token from the ADFS but SAP apparently can only handle the out of the box authentication. So I will need to authenticate the entire session.

This is what I have right now:

Retrieve the token:

```
            var binding = new WS2007HttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
            binding.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
            binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;

            var trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, new EndpointAddress(AppSettings.AdfsUrl));
            trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
            trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = user.UserName;
            trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = PasswordService.Decrypt(user.UserPassword, user.UserID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            trustChannelFactory.ConfigureChannelFactory();

            // Create issuance issuance and get security token
            var requestToken = new RequestSecurityToken(WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue);
            requestToken.AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(AppSettings.ServicePortalUrl);
            requestToken.KeyType = WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer;
            var tokenClient = (WSTrustChannel) trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
            var token = tokenClient.Issue(requestToken) as GenericXmlSecurityToken;

            return token;
```

And an attempt to get the claims so I could perhaps put the user principal in the HttpContext before redirecting to the SAP Portal. (Long shot)

```
        var tokenHandlers = new SecurityTokenHandlerCollection(new SecurityTokenHandler[] { new SamlSecurityTokenHandler() });
        tokenHandlers.First().Configuration.AudienceRestriction.AudienceMode = AudienceUriMode.Never;
        tokenHandlers.First().Configuration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
        tokenHandlers.Configuration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

        var trusted = new TrustedIssuerNameRegistry("*.domain.com");
        tokenHandlers.Configuration.IssuerNameRegistry = trusted;

        var samlToken = tokenHandlers.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(token.TokenXml.OuterXml)));
        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(tokenHandlers.ValidateToken(samlToken).First());
        HttpContext.Current.User = claimsPrincipal;
```

This does not work, as I keep on getting X509 certificate validation errors.

What I've tried:

- Providing the SAML signature as MYSAPSSO2 token (long shot, did not work)
- Putting the user principal in the HTTP context as I saw that SAP looks for an IPrincipal in the HTTP context. (Can't get it to work)
- Set the MSISAuthenticated cookie, but have not idea how to get the value (base64 timestamp of moment of authentication?)

Is there any obvious way that I'm overseeing? Basically, I just want to perform the same authentication the ADFS login page does, but in code, so the user doesn't see a second login page.

Comment: Do you have the user password? You code indicates that.

What scenario are your end users going through? You have another central authentication product - and after authentication there you want ADFS logon? I ask because it sounds kind of odd.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this ...

```
            // ######################### TOKEN HANDLER ########################################################################################################################
            var genericToken = token as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
            var handlers = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionManager.SecurityTokenHandlerCollections.First();

            // ######################## HANDLE AudienceRestriction programatically.############################################################################################
            //handlers.Configuration.AudienceRestriction.AudienceMode.Equals(0);
            handlers.Configuration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri (svcEndpoint)); // porgramatically validate AllowedAudienceUris. This is your RP. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.selectors.audienceurimode?view=netframework-4.8#fields
            // ##### HANDLE STS SIGNING CERTIFICATE VALIDATIONS. Set to none for ADFS autocertificaterollover.
            handlers.Configuration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None; //Also set in App.config / web.config 

            // ########################## HANDLE IssuerNameRegistry automatically.##############################################################################################
            
            // ######################## READ METADATA OF ADFS TO EXTRACT SIGNING CERTIFICATE ###################################################################################
            AdfsMetadataService svc = new AdfsMetadataLoader("https://" + opts.Farmname +  "/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml");
            var metadata = svc.Get();
            string IdP = metadata.Result.Identity;
            string stringSigningCert = metadata.Result.SigningCertificateString;

            // ####################### CONVERT FROM BASE64 TO READ SIGNING CERTIFICATE THUMBPRINT AND SUBJECT TO USE IN ISSUERNAMEREGISTRY #####################################
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(stringSigningCert);
            var AdfsSigncert = new X509Certificate2(bytes);

            //Console.WriteLine(IdP +  stringSigningCert + cert.Thumbprint + cert.Subject);
            var registry = new ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry();
            registry.AddTrustedIssuer(AdfsSigncert.Thumbprint, AdfsSigncert.Subject);
            handlers.Configuration.IssuerNameRegistry = registry;

            var cToken = handlers.ReadToken(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(genericToken.TokenXml.OuterXml)));
            var identity = handlers.ValidateToken(cToken).First();
            var userIdenity = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully Authenticated with identity type userIdenity.Identity.Name with value ~~~ " + userIdenity.Identity.Name);
            foreach (var c in userIdenity.Claims)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Claim Type = " + c.Type + " ~~~ Claim Value = " + c.Value);   
            }
```